# Getting translation strings for jinja2 templates integrated with django 1.x?

Tags: django, internationalization, translation, jinja2, xgettext

I can use jinj2 templates with django via render_to_response defined as below

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.exceptions import ImproperlyConfigured
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import TemplateDoesNotExist, Context
from django.utils import translation
from itertools import chain
from jinja2 import FileSystemLoader, Environment
from jinja2 import nodes
from jinja2.ext import Extension 
from django.conf import settings

import jinja_filters as jf
import traceback

from django.utils.translation import gettext, ngettext

class DjangoTranslator(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.gettext = gettext
        self.ngettext = ngettext

class DjangoEnvironment(Environment):

    def get_translator(self, context):
        return DjangoTranslator()


template_dirs = getattr(settings,'TEMPLATE_DIRS')
default_mimetype = getattr(settings, 'DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE')
global_exts = getattr(settings, 'JINJA_EXTENSIONS', ())
env = DjangoEnvironment(autoescape=False, loader=FileSystemLoader(template_dirs, encoding="utf-8"), extensions=global_exts)
env.filters.update({'myescape':jf.myescape})

if 'jinja2.ext.i18n' in global_exts:
        env.install_gettext_translations(translation)

def render_to_response(filename, context={}, context_instance=Context({}), mimetype=default_mimetype):
    template = env.get_template(filename)
    for d in context_instance.dicts:
        context.update(d)
    context.update({'settings':settings})
    rendered = template.render(**context)
    return HttpResponse(rendered, mimetype=mimetype)
```

but cannot make django extract translation strings for jinja2 templates.

seems that the lines below in django/utils/translation/trans_real.py
make it possible for makemessages command to parse django templates for i18n via templatize@trans_real.py

```
inline_re = re.compile(r"""^\s*trans\s+((?:".*?")|(?:'.*?'))\s*""")
block_re = re.compile(r"""^\s*blocktrans(?:\s+|$)""")
endblock_re = re.compile(r"""^\s*endblocktrans$""")
plural_re = re.compile(r"""^\s*plural$""")
constant_re = re.compile(r"""_\(((?:".*?")|(?:'.*?'))\)""")
```

is there a nicer way than modifying the makemessages.py by rewriting translation tags regexes for local use on jinja2 templates to extract translation strings?

Answer (score 2):

A little modification made it for me.. Base recipe is as follows,
you might need to add/modify some more to fit your needs.

```
$ ~ > cp $DJANGO_PATH/utils/translation/ myproject/utils/ -a
```

and make the modifications given below:

```
$ ~ > diff $DJANGO_PATH/utils/translation/trans_real.py myproject/utils/translation/trans_real.py  -u

--- utils/translation/trans_real.py     Wed Jan 20 05:07:46 2010
+++ myproject/utils/translation/trans_real.py    Wed Jan 20 04:51:39 2010
@@ -435,6 +435,9 @@
 endblock_re = re.compile(r"""^\s*endblocktrans$""")
 plural_re = re.compile(r"""^\s*plural$""")
 constant_re = re.compile(r"""_\(((?:".*?")|(?:'.*?'))\)""")

+jinja_block_re = re.compile(r"""^\s*trans(?:\s+|$)""")
+jinja_endblock_re = re.compile(r"""^\s*endtrans$""")

 def templatize(src):
     """
@@ -451,7 +454,7 @@
     for t in Lexer(src, None).tokenize():
         if intrans:
             if t.token_type == TOKEN_BLOCK:
-                endbmatch = endblock_re.match(t.contents)
+                endbmatch = jinja_endblock_re.match(t.contents)
                 pluralmatch = plural_re.match(t.contents)
                 if endbmatch:
                     if inplural:
@@ -485,7 +488,7 @@
         else:
             if t.token_type == TOKEN_BLOCK:
                 imatch = inline_re.match(t.contents)
-                bmatch = block_re.match(t.contents)
+                bmatch = jinja_block_re.match(t.contents)
                 cmatches = constant_re.findall(t.contents)
                 if imatch:
                     g = imatch.group(1)


$ ~ > cp $DJANGO_PATH/core/management/commands/makemessages.py myproject/myapp/management/commands/ 


$ ~/myproject/ > diff  $DJANGO_PATH/core/management/commands/makemessages.py main/management/commands/makemessages.py -u
--- /usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemessages.py    Wed Jan 20 05:08:37 2010
+++ main/management/commands/makemessages.py    Wed Jan 20 05:28:41 2010
@@ -56,7 +56,7 @@
     else:
         settings.configure(USE_I18N = True)

-    from django.utils.translation import templatize
+    from myproject.utils.translation import templatize

     if os.path.isdir(os.path.join('conf', 'locale')):
         localedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.join('conf', 'locale'))
```

then calling make messages as follows does the trick

```
$ ~/myproject/ > ./manage.py mymakemessages -l $LANGUAGE -e .jinja -v 2
```

my templates are named as templ_name.jinja, you'll need to replace .jinja 
in the command above with whatever extension you use for your template names.

Comment: I've also made a package to ease django - jinja integration, with support for translation strings. https://github.com/altunyurt/djtemps

Answer (score 1):

I've added support for this to Coffin, based on this approach:

http://github.com/miracle2k/coffin/commit/ba1a8a510b05074731d383e0dc1f7c21c67ff728